# Every viewports acts as stretchviewport

Tags: libgdx

I have a viewport and camera setup, but whenever I render, the viewport acts as a StretchViewport and fills my entire screen instead of keeping the aspect ratio and adding black bars. Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong or how to fix it?

I got this code in my GameScreen class to setup the camera and viewport:

```
private static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 468;
private static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 293;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private FitViewport viewport;

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,camera);
    viewport.apply();

    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    camera.update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    // do drawing
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width,height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
}
```

Full code:

```
package com.Sidescroll.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    private static final int VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 468;
    private static final int VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 293;

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private BitmapFont font;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport viewport;
    private int deltaCount;
    private float deltaSum;
    private float fps;

    private Level level;
    private Player player;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        level = new Level();
        player = new Player(level.getSpawn());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH,VIRTUAL_HEIGHT,camera);
        viewport.apply();
        System.out.println(camera.viewportWidth);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        camera.update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        player.update(delta);

       deltaCount += 1;
       deltaSum += delta;

        if(deltaSum >= 1) {
            fps = 1/(deltaSum/deltaCount);

            deltaCount = 0;
            deltaSum = 0;
        }

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        level.draw(batch, player);
        font.draw(batch, "FPS: " + fps, 0, 293);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width,height);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        font.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
        level.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: checked your code and it behaves as FitViewport not Fill :) are you sure it is not working ok? I've added one texture to render - everything else was copy-pasted

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine as well. Should work as intented.

Comment: Ok i added the full code, does that help? its not much changed/added

Comment: @m.antkowicz I added the full code, does that help? Im drawing the level and player by passing the batch to the draw functions and then simply rendering the textures

Comment: hi, still works perfect... :) Maybe you expect something else from it although it works as should? Please look [at this](http://imgur.com/KGZk7jp) - I've added just a texture but the FitViewports adds black stripes as it should. Please show your screenshot with explanationwhy it is wrong

Comment: @m.antkowicz http://imgur.com/a/pC1BG this is how it looks and should look. I have no idea why this is happening, can it be caused by code in another class like the DesktopLauncher.java ? im also not using tile2d or scene2d, I just draw the rectangles and background with sprites

Comment: are you using xOS? [Here's what I found](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1620) although it was fixed - what version of Libgdx are you using? The fact is I'm testing your code on Windows

Comment: @m.antkowicz im also using windows and i have release 1.5.4, ill try to do the same thing in another project in a bit

Comment: @m.antkowicz EDIT: I just redid it, instead of setting up a game class and setting a screen where i render (with super.render() in the class extending game) i just implemented applicationlistener in the first class without any screen and it worked. This means, there must be something going on with either the super.render() in the class extending game, which messes something up, or just the fact that the other one is a screen or something, really strange, if you know why this happens, would be nice to know

Comment: weird things are happening here... :) ok what comes to my mind: 1. share whole project (by some dropbox or anything) - maybe there is issue in other class? 2. try on the other computer or just the newest libgdx - maybe there is version problem? 3. check your desktop launcher - it should looks like http://pastebin.com/FS5uBZzm - not very possible but maybe you have some option there set?

Comment: ok then please add your game class to the question - I will try the combination game and screen and maybe then I will se the issue

Comment: @m.antkowicz i uploaded the files https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wsxamxj9q6e4rkf/AAAqLLH7Z1Mbw5d-2mYJMUj8a?dl=0 this is the setup with the class extending game. Ty for trying so hard to find the problem

Comment: @m.antkowicz Found the mistake, everything works now, I had a resize method in screen and one in the class extending game... guess which one was empty and didnt say "super.resize(width,height);" took me way too long to find that one, wow, do i need super.x(); in every method i override in class extending game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to also call resize in the class extending game

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
}
```